# Want JS function to use ajax to run PHP and then output PHP on page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to have javascript run some PHP code and then print the results from the PHP code on the page.  I found some code that does this using ajax and also putting the PHP code in an external file.  The code I found seems to run the PHP code in an "alert" dialog box, and I cannot figure out how to have it just display the output of the PHP on the current page.

I am new to this so learning, the "success" function has alert(response) so I know why it is doing the alert; but I am trying to make it print it on the page instead and cannot get it to do that…

here is my JS with ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var answer = "gman wants a function to run php";
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://jba.gtdsites.com/script.php',
data: 'answer=' + answer,
success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
}
});
</script>
```

here is the external PHP file (script.php):

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
    && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
) {
    // AJAX request
    $answer = $_GET['answer'];
    echo "answer is: " . $answer;
    ?>
    <br/>
    <?php
    echo "<br/>this is working.";
    // ...
}
?>
```

I have been reading a lot trying to figure this out but not connecting the dots and not getting anywhere; so I am wondering if someone can tell me how to get it to just output the PHP stuff on the page instead of doing an alert?

Thanks so much...

Comment: So your question is how to change the content of an existing element on the page / in the DOM?

Comment: jQuery's `append`, `text`, `html` or any number of other methods will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a div inside your document with id 'ajax_content' just replace

```
alert(response);
```

with

```
$('#ajax_content').html(response);
```

Comment: I think you mean `$('ajax_content').html(response);`

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, yes you right. $('ajax_content').html(response) or   $('ajax_content').innerHTML = response are some of options. Thanks for correction.

Comment: `$('ajax_content').innerHTML = response;` still isn't quite right.  `.innerHTML` is a property of a DOM element, not a jQuery object.  You *could* do `$('ajax_content').get(0).innerHTML = response;`, but that's just silly compared to `$('ajax_content').html(response);`.

Comment: thanks so much TP, NS and RH, been struggling with the answers but when the answer with the # added in it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can append/replace you ajax response in your required html element. Like if your html element inside which you want to print is:

```
<div id="div-to-print-ajax-response"></div>
```

then your JS function would be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var answer = "gman wants a function to run php";
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://jba.gtdsites.com/script.php',
data: 'answer=' + answer,
success: function(response) {
    $('div-to-print-ajax-response').html(response);
}
});
</script>
```